# Angular 1 ng-repeat with filter for split the string values within same json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split, angularjs-ng-repeat

I used the ng-repeat to append the json array value  ,the problem is pictureURLS object is having the string value of images what I am looking separate the pictureURLS string value' and display the images

javascript

```
 var results= [
                {
                   "title": Album1,
                   "pictureURLS": "pirul.jpg,picurl2.jpg,picurl3.jpg",
                   "ApprovalStatus": "2",


                },
                {
                   "title": Album2,
                   "pictureURLS": "pirul.jpg,picurl2.jpg,picurl3.jpg",
                   "ApprovalStatus": "2",


                },
                {
                   "title": Album3,
                   "AlbumPictureURLS": null,
"ApprovalStatus": "2",

             ]
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in results">
<h4>{{photo.title}}</h4>
<img src="{{photo.pictureURLS}}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this;

```
<img ng-repeat="url in photo.pictureURLS.split(',')" src="{{url}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your objects then you can make it to contain the URLs as an array by adding a property as shown below

```
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    var pictureURLArray = results[i].pictureURLS.split(',');
    results[i].pictureURLArray = pictureURLArray;
}
```

Then you can use one more `ng-repeat` in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in results">
<h4>{{photo.title}}</h4>
<div ng-repeat="url in photo.pictureURLArray">
    <img src="{{url}}" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="photo in results">
       <h4>{{photo.title}}</h4>
         <div ng-repeat="url in photo.pictureURLS.split(',')">
            <img ng-src="{{url}}" />
         </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: 100% this will work fine in case of you. without writting the code in the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
Correct JSON format to:

var results= 
           [{
               title: "Album1",
               pictureURLS: "pirul.jpg,picurl2.jpg,picurl3.jpg",
               ApprovalStatus: "2"
            },
            {
               title: "Album2",
               pictureURLS: "pirul.jpg,picurl2.jpg,picurl3.jpg",
               ApprovalStatus: "2"
            },
            {
               title: "Album3",
               AlbumPictureURLS: null
            }];

visit fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/1248/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in results">
    <h4>{{photo.title}}</h4>
    <img ng-repeat="ph in photo.pictureURLS | filterPhoto" src="{{ph}}" />
</div>
```

Js:

```
myApp.filter('filterPhoto', function() {
    return function(x) {
        return x.split(',');
    };
});
```

Hope this will work.